# python telegram bot record information

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

Please tell me how to write data after the user clicks the button? The buttons will constantly change:

```
elif message.text == ' Запись на тест-драйв':
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    for i in cl:
        button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=i, callback_data="button")
        keyboard.add(button)
    sent_te = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите автомобиль из списка:', reply_markup=keyboard)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(sent_te, test_drive_auto)
```

Doing:

```
def test_drive_auto(message):
    open('testdriveauto.txt', 'w').write(message.text)
```

But the recording doesn't happen. The code then continues:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_worker(call):
    if call.data == "button":
        sent_tetstdrive = bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text="Напишите Ваше имя")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(sent_tetstdrive, testdrive)
```